# ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'itertools' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm getting that error when I try to run my program in python 3 in Conda version 4.9.2

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "mosaic.py", line 1, in <module> from itertools import pairwise ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise' from 'itertools' (unknown location)`

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I was able to get around this by using `more-itertools`. `from more_itertools import pairwise`

Comment: probably `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for itertools`

you can use more-itertools as mentioned above

Comment: Sounds like you were using Python 3.9 or earlier? In 3.9, `pairwise` is not in itertools yet, it's a recipe in `more-itertools`. (The Conda version is irrelevant, that's just a package manager).

Answer (score 6):

This function is available in Python^3.10 ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)).